# My action links on my nodes are not visible

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

My action links (view, edit, note export, devel)  on my nodes are not visible, i've been working like this for a while ignoring it, but now its becoming kind of annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used or created hook_menu_alter() hook in any module ?

Comment: If you change themes, does the problem persist?

Comment: If your view action links are missing, then in all probability you didn't print view classes, such as "view view-[view name] view-id-[view id] view-display-id-page ... ". But if you mean system action links like "show" or "edit" then probably you didn't rendering tabs in your page.tpl file.